# Grep from specific file and print after matching strings

Tags: awk, grep, match

I want to get grep matching output from 2 list files, but still print the previous information.

Here are the example files and the wanted output.

**Input_1**

```
AAAAA
CCCCC
DDDDD
EEEEE
```

**Input_2 (tab_delimited) (there might be some blank cells)**

```
AAAAA:1    -          -
-       BBBBB:0.5     -
-          -       CCCCC:0.2
-       DDDDD:0       -
```

**Wanted output**

```
AAAAA:1
CCCCC:0.2
DDDDD:0
```

I have been trying all sorts of grep options and couldn't figure it out. Other methods (other than using grep) are all welcome!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: This might help you out. Have a look at the `man` pages of grep to understand what this is doing. `grep -Fwf input1 <(grep -oE $'[^-\t]+' input2)`

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. I am new to this community. I will definitely do as what you said for next posting @ravinderSingh13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -Eof <(awk '{print $0":[0-9.]+"}' <input1>) <input2>
```

I use awk to change input1 and create patterns that input2 can match.